# Can I use the "Open with..." context menu item within zip folders?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, zip

Normally in windows explorer, there is an "Open with..." item in the context menu, that allows choosing a non-default program to open the file with.

When within a zip folder, this menu item is missing. Is there any way to reenable it, short of extracting the zip? Perhaps a registry change, or a shell extension?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way. The built-in Zip viewer of Windows doesn't allows this.
Just use WinRAR or 7zip or simply unzip the file.